# Batch Script for Concatenate multiple raw/binary files - Windows command line < reads from a filtered file and pass it to another cmd

Tags: windows, command-line

I have different types of file in the same folder, which I have filtered and redirected to a list.txt file, using a separate script.

List.txt has the name of the binary files , which I need to combine together into one binary file.

```
>type list.txt
a.raw
b.raw
c.raw
```

Concatenate all the files present in the list.txt to a final.raw file.

```
>type < list.txt > final.raw
 The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Please let me know if there is any option to achieve this on windows cmdline or through some script file.

Note : manually both type and copy cmd is working properly for concatenation. need a script or cmd to do the same.

Comment: @harrymc : the solution is not present in the question link shared or marked duplicate. update the question too.

Answer (score 0):

If files to be concatenated are textual, then you may use

```
@echo.>final.raw && @for /f %x in (list.txt) do @type "%x" >> final.raw
```

If files to be concatenated are binary (really - in any case), then use

```
@echo.>final.raw && @for /f %x in (list.txt) do @copy /b final.raw+"%x" > nul
```

If filenames may contain spaces then use

```
@echo.>final.raw && @for /f "tokens=*" %x in (list.txt) do @copy /b final.raw+"%x" > nul
```

If the file `final.raw` already exists and may NOT be cleared then remove `@echo.>final.raw &&` from the command line.

For using in .BAT file you may double each percent sign.

Comment: Tried it in cmdline and putting it into batch file it is not working ..

Comment: In .BAT you must double percent signs. In command line - it must work, except the case when concatenated files are binary.

Comment: tried this in batch file : for /f %%x in (list.txt) do @type %%x >> final.raw, all the files are binary file.

Comment: @mail2subhajit *all the files are binary file* You should specify this in the question. Edited.

Comment: updated the question, now only the first file is taken from list.txt, other files are not getting concatenated.

Comment: @mail2subhajit *only the first file is taken from list.txt, other files are not getting concatenated.* It is strange, I have tested, and 3 binary files were successfully concatenated from the command line.

Comment: The list.txt file has data in new line or return after each file name (CRLF) ex:  a.raw\n b.raw \n .. so on. I hope your list.txt also have the same.

Comment: @mail2subhajit Yes, absolutely the same.

Comment: Thanks @Akina .. i will try to figure out the problem and update it here.